# What is the number of independent sets in graph of this type?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-colorings, extremal-graph-theory

Suppose we have a graph $G(V,E)$

[image]

What is the number of independent sets in graph of this type?

I have an idea to use reccurence
$$|G|=|G\backslash \{v\}|+|G\backslash n(v)|$$
where $|G|$ is the number all possible independent sets of graph G,
$v$ is an arbitrary vertex, and $n(v)$ is a set of all vertex's adjacent with $v$ and $v$ itself.

But may be there some better ideas or results?

Comment: In the case of this reader, I'd need a more careful formulation to understand the q.

Comment: Consider (linear) graph: # --- # --- # --- #, and let A B C D be different colors. Is A --- B --- C --- D a tolerant coloring? Is A --- A --- A --- A tolerant?

Comment: Normally, these things are called "independent subsets", not colorings.

Comment: @WlodAA what q do you mean?

Comment: @WlodAA there is only colour - black. all other verices are supposed to be uncolored.

Comment: So you have a classical coloring: Two colors (black and white), no two adjacent vertices should have the same color. Now, given a graph (e.g. the one in your image), you want to compute the total number of different colorings that are possible on this graph (if any are possible at all, i.e. the chromatic number of the graph is $\leq 2$). Does that match your question?

Comment: Google for "the number of independent sets in a graph".

Comment: @DirkLiebhold almost yes, but no two adjacent vertices should be black, they can be white. it is more correct to call it "independent subsets" in place og colorings, as said EmilJeřábek.

Comment: I ve fixed the question.

Comment: It seems, if I understood the problem (I am not so sure), that there should be $2^c$ tolerant colorings, where $c$ is the number of the connectivity  components.

Comment: graph is connected, look to the question again @WlodAA

Comment: Then,in the connected case, there are two colorings, white and black.  Obviously, you didn't mean such triviality. But now I see a completely new formulation. This new formulation is of course simple and clear.